# Reading Heart Rate Sensor off Microsoft Band using Windows IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: microsoft-band, windowsiot

When attempting to read Heart Rate Sensor from a Microsoft Band paired with a Raspberry Pi2 running latest Windows IoT Core (10586).  I get an exception when calling:

“bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.RequestUserConsentAsync()”

It would seem that the IoT Core does not contain the necessary libraries to create the popup dialog that is seen on other devices when executing this method.

Are there plans to extend the Band SDK to support Windows IoT Core in this scenario?

Are there any proposed workarounds?

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 IoT is currently not supported by the Microsoft Band SDK. In particular, the user consent prompts run on the device that the band is paired with and in this case the required APIs for user prompts are not supported in the Windows 10 IoT Core APIs.

If you require this in a future release of the SDK please open a request at the Microsoft Health User Voice page https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com